# "Thou hast cleft my heart in twain"

Tags: verbs

"Thou hast cleft my heart in twain" says Gertrude to Hamlet. 'Cleft' is from 'cleave' meaning divide or split. Yet, I often meet constructions such as 'clefts' 'clefted' or 'clefting' in the writings of English native speakers.
Has 'cleft' shifted to an infinitive in the modern usage? Or is it likely to?
Believe it or not I've also encountered this construction in a newspaper: 'He clefts my heart in twain'. 
As a nonnative speaker of English I find this confusing.

Anyone to shed some light?

Comment: "Often" in native English writing? Only the most pretentious writer would use any derivation of 'cleft'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In linguistics, there is a construction called a cleft sentence (e.g., *It is grammar that is at question.*) The transformation between the more standard structure and this is called *[clefting](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13777323)*, which I believe is a back formation. Outside that, I would guess it's an error. I can't find examples of verb *[clefts](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13777282)* in the Corpus of Current American English and of the two examples of *[clefted](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13777285)*, one looks like it might be a specialized medical usage.

One problem with *cleave* is that it has these two different irregular past tense and past participle forms: *cleft/clove* and *cleft/cloven*. Another is that it means its own opposite (both to split and to join).

Comment: So it's an error. You answered my question. Thank you

Comment: Googling, it appears that *cleft/clefted/clefting* is indeed a technical term in medical jargon and in linguistics, and otherwise is probably an error.

Answer (score 0):

The conjugation is to cleave, cleft, cloven. The simple past tense is cleft. The past participle is cloven.

Comment: Actually, the verb "cleave" has multiple conjugations. The OED says "Pa. tense clove, clave, cleaved, cleft; Pa. pple. cloven, clove, cleaved, cleft"

Answer (score -1):

The line "Thou has cleft my heart in twain," as written in the Shakespearean play Hamlet, basically means "You have broken my heart." Many words used by Shakespeare are no longer commonly used in modern English in the same context if they are used at all. Therefore, if you are looking to find a comparable word for cleft in modern English, it would be something like broken (i.e. You have broken my heart.)

I know this question was asked several years ago, but nonetheless, hope I helped to clear things up.

Comment: He did not write *thou has*, which is ungrammatical.  The second person is *thou hast*.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP appears to know this already, and is asking about the use of _cleft_ as a (present or infinitive) verb.